MissingPluginException fluttertoast on IOS
I'm getting a MissingPluginException (No implementation found for method showToast error while running in for IOS after implementing some SDK with native swift files(not sure if the project runs without the integrated SDK).
I've tried

flutter clean
removed Pods and Podfile.loc
uninstalled old build
closed and reopened project
made sure the package fluttertoast supports ios

